# Application stops when I hit the "Done" button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, when I hit the "Done" button, whenever I am in the Movie Player, my app goes back to the previous menu, while a loading sign is in the middle of the screen. Then my app stops completely, without any error messages.

Here's my code:

```
_streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
        if(self.streamPlayer != nil){
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                       object:_streamPlayer];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:)
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                                       object:_streamPlayer];
```

EDIT: I implemented the 2 functions like this:

```
-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSNumber *reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    switch ([reason intValue]) {
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
            NSLog(@"Playback ended");
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
            [self alertWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"The video can't open!", @"The video can't open!")];

            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
            NSLog(@"User Exited");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(IBAction) doneButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.streamPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.streamPlayer = nil;

}
```

I'm not sure about the second one! Still the same problem!
Any ideas?

Comment: Where's the "Done" button? What are you expecting to happen by hitting that? Please provide some more context. Your question is ambiguous at the moment.

Comment: The "Done" button is on the bar and i expect, when i press it, to go back to the previous menu, so can i select (if i want) another video to play.

Comment: And have you put a break point on the first line and stepped through the code?

Comment: I did but i didn't manage to make it work..

Comment: I doubt you actually did because breakpoints aren't intended to 'make it work', but to give you an idea of exactly which line it's crashing on, which makes debugging easier.

Comment: What error / crash message do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I commented the second method (doneButtonClick:) and it's implementation and then, when the video player should stop playing, i added this:

```
[_streamPlayer stop];
[_streamPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
[self dismissLoadingView];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to add a notification center observer references a method named `doneButtonClick:`. However, the method you implemented is named `doneButtonClicked:` (note the 'ed' at the end!). As such, you'll get a crash when the notification comes in because the method you specified doesn't exit. You need to either:

1. Change the `addObserver` call to reference the actual method: `@selector(doneButtonClicked:)` or
2. Rename your method to match the `addObserver` call: `- (IBAction)doneButtonClick:(id)sender`

Incidentally, I'd rename the method and `@selector` reference to `doneButtonTapped` - users tap on a touch device, they don't 'click'.